# Find $a_{11}$ and $a_{22}$ given two eigen-values?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is one question on my homework, and I can't seem to find how to solve it online (not sure how to word it in a search) or in the textbook.

Determine $a_{11}$ and $a_{22}$ for
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & -2.4 \\
1.6 & a_{22} 
\end{pmatrix}$$
if $\lambda_1 =2$, $\lambda_2 =5$ and $a_{11}>a_{22}$.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Is lambdas eigenvalues?

Comment: Call the matrix $A$, you know by hypothesis that $det(A-2I)=0$ and $det(A-5I)=0$.  Try to use this

Comment: the trace of the matrix is the sum of the eigenvalues, and the determinant, the product

Comment: @ChinnapparajR Yes.

Comment: Irrelevant to the question, but *eigenvalues* is a compound, unhyphenated word

Answer (score 1):

Since 4 and 5 are eigenvalues, we know that the characteristic polynomial is ($\lambda$ - 4)($\lambda$-5) = $\lambda^2 - 9 \lambda+20$. But if we compute the characteristic polynomial of the given matrix we get $\lambda^2 - (a_{11}+a_{22})\lambda + 3.84+a_{11}a_{22}$. So we have

$$ a_{11}+a_{22} = 9\\a_{11}a_{22} = 16.16$$

You can now solve for $a_{11}, a_{22}$.

Comment: Thank you!  That makes sense, and I was able to apply that to the problem.

Comment: eigen values are $~2~$ and $~5~$ , not $~4~$ and $~5~$

Answer (score 1):

Here $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & -2.4 \\
1.6 & a_{22} 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Given that the two eigen-value of $~A~$ are $~\lambda_1 =2\quad \text{and}\quad \lambda_2 =5~$ and also $~a_{11}>a_{22}$ .

Now $~Trace~ (A)= a_{11}+a_{22}=2+5=7$

and $~Determinant ~(A)=a_{11}~a_{22}~-~(-2.4)~(1.6)=10$

$\implies a_{11}~a_{22}~=6.16$

So we have two equations $$a_{11}+a_{22}= 7$$and $$a_{11}~a_{22}~=6.16$$

Solving we have $$a_{11}=\frac{7}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt {609}}{10},\quad a_{22}=\frac{7}{2}\mp\frac{\sqrt {609}}{10}$$
Since  $~a_{11}>a_{22}~$,so $$a_{11}=\frac{7}{2}+\frac{\sqrt {609}}{10},\quad a_{22}=\frac{7}{2}-\frac{\sqrt {609}}{10}$$

Comment: nice approach -- I suggested it myself in the comments -- but I don't think $i$ should be there

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. Thanks @J.W.Tanner